# Reveal.js - Full screen images within a specific div tag

Tags: reveal.js

I am trying to implement this so that I can get something like below:

```
<body>
<div class="topNavigation">
 ...
 some dynamic stuff that appears at the top of the bage
</div>

<div class=reveal>
 ...
<section data-background="https://s3.amazonaws.com/hakim-static/reveal-js/cornify.gif">
 ..
</section>

</div>

</body>
```

So what I need is a top navigation before the slides, but I also want the slides to fill the full page of the remaining content. Is this possible?

Out of the box it looks like data-background attaches to the  tag and adds a background image - can I get this to happen on different div?